# overriding axis labels after plot in R -- not working if plotting an scb object?

Tags: r, plot

What should I check about the object I plot to be able to override the axis labels, which remain variable names generated be the scb call instead of my specification below? scb is in the locfit library: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/locfit/locfit.pdf

```
fit2<-scb(closed_rule ~ lp(bl),deg=1,xlim=c(0,1),ev=lfgrid(100), family='binomial',alpha=cbind(0,0.3),kern="parm")
pdf('figure1.pdf')
plot(fit2,ylab = "Predicted closed rule probability", xlab="Lobbyist bias", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
dev.off()
```

I found no relevant object of fit2 to override -- and I am not even sure why this should be necessary if I specify labels myself. I see one called varnames, that has a single element corresponding to the future x-axis label, but overriding it does not help my labels show, and the ylabel is definitely coming from some completely other place anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axis labels are kind of predefine in the plot.scb function.

If you type `> plot.scb` you will see that either `plot.scb.1d` or `plot.scb.2d` are used.

`plot.scb.1d` use the content of `fit2$vnames[1]` for the x axis. To change the ylab value you will have to hack the function by replacing the plot line in `plot.scb.1d` by something like that:

```
...
plot(x$xev, fit, type = "l", ylim = yl, ylab = "Predicted closed rule probability", xlab="Lobbyist bias")
...
```

For `plot.scb.2d` it is easier `xlab=fit2$vnames[1]` and `ylab=fit2$vnames[2]`. Here, I would change the value(s) of `fit2$vnames`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I never knew how I can quickly check a built-in function, nor that if I simply define my own in the code after importing the library but calling the function in the code, I can simply overwrite it. That said, I find it surprising that there was not other way to overwrite variable labels or limits for this graph.